# PHP: Concatenating database results by email

Tags: php, mysql

I have a list of tasks assigned to multiple users. I'd like to set up a cron job and send out email notifications once an hour to each user. Here's my query:

```
SELECT t.*, u.name, u.email
FROM tasks t, users u
WHERE t.date_created > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR) AND t.user_id = u.id
ORDER BY t.date_created ASC
```

Here's the result (I trimmed a few columns to fit better):

```
+----+-------+---------------------+---------+--------+------+--------------+
| id | title |     date_created    | user_id | status | name |     email    |
+----+-------+---------------------+---------+--------+------+--------------+
| 9  | task1 | 2013-09-01 17:56:10 |    2    | active | John | js@gmail.com |
| 10 | task2 | 2013-09-01 17:57:20 |    1    | active | Tim  | ti@gmail.com |
| 11 | task3 | 2013-09-01 17:58:30 |    2    | active | John | js@gmail.com |
| 12 | task4 | 2013-09-01 17:59:40 |    1    | active | Tim  | ti@gmail.com |
+----+-------+---------------------+---------+--------+------+--------------+
```

The problem is that I can't figure out how to concatenate the tasks belonging to a certain user_id and then send them out to the assigned email. So for the above example there would be two emails sent out:

1. task1 and task 3 (to js@gmail.com)
2. task2 and task 4 (to ti@gmail.com)

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking for but try `GROUP BY email` or `GROUP BY user_id`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with the `GROUP_CONCAT` aggregate command :

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(t.title), u.name, u.email
FROM tasks t, users u
WHERE t.date_created > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR) AND t.user_id = u.id
GROUP BY u.id
```

This will output something like :

```
task1,task3 | John | js@gmail.com
task2,task4 | Tim  | ti@gmail.com
```

Default is a comma delimited string, but you can specify another separator like this : `GROUP_CONCAT(t.title,' and ')`

Comment: Thanks! You can also use `SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(t.title) as title` to change the column heading.